# How to collapse two columns into one in SAS

Tags: sas, data-manipulation, data-transform

What I have

A dataset with 8 row x4 col

```
"Condition" "A_1" "B_1"
A            1     .
A            3     .
A            2     .
A            4     .
B            .     4
B            .     3
B            .     5
B            .     6
```

[[image: What I ][1]]

What I want is either:
[What I want 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNs7c.png)
(1)

```
"Condition" "A_1" "B_1"
A            1     .
A            3     .
A            2     .
A            4     .
B            4     .
B            3     .
B            5     .
B            6     .
```

OR, (2):
[What I want 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxcBn.png)

```
"Condition" "A_1" "B_1" "AB_1"
A            1     .     1
A            3     .     3
A            2     .     2
A            4     .     4
B            .     4     4
B            .     3     3
B            .     5     5
B            .     6     6
```

It was easy with STATA, R, and Excel (of course), but for the life of me I can't figure out this simple thing in SAS.

I tried,

```
data want;
if condition = "B" then A_1 = B_1;
set have;
run;
```

I also tried

```
data want;
if condition = "A" then AB_1 = A_1;
else AB_1 = B_1;
set have;
run;
```

The second code almost does the job except that the resulting AB_1 lags by 1 row.
What the hack...

Comment: You have to put SET before the IF statements and then either of your programs should work.

Comment: Just adds some PUT statements to check the values of the variables before and after each of the statements and it should be obvious what you have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce`. You also need your `set` statement before doing any of your logic. SAS reads a row when it encounters the `set` statement.

```
data want;
    set have;
    AB_1 = coalesce(A_1, B_1);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

for (2) you can try to use [cats()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/n1e21rr6al5m2nn19r1fat5qxwrt.htm) function

```
data want;
  set have;
  AB_1 = cats(A_1,B_1);
run;
```

But in order to do the concatenate columns of different types you should also use the explicit PUT() function.